# c++ Qt: catching a segfault from dll

Tags: c++, qt, dll, segmentation-fault, qlibrary

I'm loading an external dll with QLibrary. In some cases the dll just crashes (seg. fault). The DLL does not throw exceptions. What is the best way to handle this? I read that I need to run in a separate process/thread. Is this the only option?

cheers,
m.

Comment: The best way is to find and solve the crash.

Comment: If you do not control the external library, then yes, the separate process (not thread) is the only option.

Comment: But maybe it crashes due to invalid parameters you pass into the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do anything with a segfault, you can try run the crashing code in a separate thread but that has the risk of leaving you with leaking resources or a massive amount of inconsistent state in your application.

If the .dll is yours I'd recommend trying to fix the segfault, if it's not report it as a bug and try work around it.